# send fieldset values by jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

look at this code :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetFacilities(string id)
{
    int hotelid = System.Convert.ToInt32(Tools.DecryptString(id));

    string ret = "";

    foreach (var item in new FacilityGroupBL().Load())
    {
        if(item.Facilities.Count != 0)
        {
            ret += "<fieldset>";
            if (item.Facilities.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var subitem in item.Facilities)
                {
                    if (subitem.HotelFacilities.Where(obj => obj.HotelId == hotelid).Count() != 0)
                        ret += "<input type='checkbox' checked='false' />" + subitem.Name;
                    else
                        ret += "<input type='checkbox' checked='true' />" + subitem.Name;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ret += "There is no facility in this fieldset.";
                ret += "</fieldset>";
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;

}
```

by this code i load some checkboxes in a DIV,then user change some checkboxes and press the SAVE button.at this time ,i should send the values of these checkboxes to server to update my data in database.by i dont know how?:( please help

note: my default code for this probem is here but it does not work($("#FacilitiesDIV input[type=checkbox]").serializeArray() is empty)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "HotelsList.aspx/SaveFacilities",
    data: "{ 'id' : '" + $("#HiddenField").val() + "', 'Facilities' : '" + $("#FacilitiesDIV input[type=checkbox]").serializeArray() + "' }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {

    },
    error: function () {
        $('#dialogMessage').dialog('open');
        $('#dialogMessage span').html("Operation Error");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$("#FacilitiesDIV input[type=checkbox]").serializeArray() since you are referring element using "#" then you need to give the fieldset element an Unique ID assuming you have 
html like

```
 <fieldset>  <input type='checkbox' checked='false' /> some text
             <input type='checkbox' checked='false' /> some text 
    </fieldset>

set the id to element <fieldset id = 'FacilitiesDIV'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should work if you give each checkbox a name, ie:

```
<input type='checkbox' checked='false' name="mycheckboxes" />
```

Comment: aaa , i check it in firebug,the problem is the browser do not send the values, i think add a name attribute is not the solution dude,bye thanks ;-)